# Two titles on sitelink in Google Search results- Title & Watermark

Tags: html, css

I recently made a test website for practice. Everything just works fine, except that my title watermark appears next to title on Google Search results (ex. I get "Contact - Contact us" instead of just "Contact"). Tried to remove it but then the page title looks empty and weird without that watermark. So i'm interested is there other solution to hide it just from Google Search results (Note: tried with visibility:hidden; didn't help)?

Code:

```
<h1 class="page-title">
                        CONTACT
                        <span class="watermark">Contact Us</span>
                    </h1>
```

Result:
[CONTACT Contact Us](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6STA.png)

Answer (score 0):

use "<'p' hidden>...</'p'>"

note: delete ' in p.

```html
 <h1 class="page-title">CONTACT<p hidden><span class="watermark">Contact Us</span></p></h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Code you sent hides watermark from page and I would like it to stay on page but remove it from Google Search results (it shows watermark next to page title and I don't like it, doesn't seem professional).